# IntelliJ and SonarQube , Local Variable is redundant

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube

IntelliJ is saying Local Variable is redundant. I placed the equation there to store it, so I can debug/see the variable before returning it. Is there any easy way to debug, or else, I would have to copy the whole variable equation in the debugger window to see its value.

[image]

Comment: If you are only using it to debug and will later remove it then there is no problem. The warning is showing because you store it in a variable and return the value without doing anything.

Comment: Also there is something called "watch" window where you can add statements and check their values during execution.

Comment: And you can "alt-click" an expression while in debug mode and it will be evaluated directly inside the IDE.

Comment: hi @knittl feel free to type as answer, and I can send points, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA offers several ways to evaluate expressions while in debug mode:

1. The obvious one, by hovering over a variable or by having a look at the [automatically added local variable watches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#variables). This is what you are doing now, but forces you to change the code in such a way that you have such a variable and some static code analysis tools will complain.
2. Add a [manual watch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#watches) for the variable or expression you are interested in.
3. Select an expression or subexpression, right click and select [Quick Evaluate Expression](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#evaluating-expressions)
4. Hover over a (sub-)expression, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left click

Note that point 2–4 will *re*-evaluate any expression. If you have side effects or non-idempotent expressions, you might not want to do this. In that case, your only choice is a temporary and redundant variable.